# Process list of URLs in synchronous manner, one by one?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

We have some list of URLs:

```
var urls = ['http://google.com','http://yahoo.com','http://yandex.com'];
```

Our task is to loop through this list of URLs and ...

- create for URL, remember `tabId`
- attach listener to `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted` with `tabId` filters
- wait for 3 seconds after last `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted` even occured
- detach listeners
- continue to next URL

I need to process every next URL only after previous URL processed successfully. I don't need to run them in parallel.

Here is the code that will run in parallel. How to modify it to run in synchronous manner, one by one?

```
var processURL = function(url) {

    //var that contains timestamp of last chrome.webRequest.onCompleted event
    var lastOnCompletedTimestamp = null;

    //our listeners that will be attached
    var webRequestListeners = {
        onCompleted : function(details) {
            lastOnCompletedTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
        }
    }   

    //method to attach web request listener
    var attachWebRequestListeners = function(tabId) {
        chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
            webRequestListeners.onCompleted,
            {urls: [ "<all_urls>" ], types : ["main_frame"], tabId : tabId},
            ['responseHeaders']         
        )
    }

    //method to detach web request listener
    var detachWebRequestListeners = function(tabId) {
        //Attention: I'm not sure is it possible to detach webRequest listeners 
        //for tabId; I was unable to find any description for that at Chrome Extension API docs
    }

    //method 
    var onTabCreated = function(tab) {
        var tabId = tab.tabId;
        attachWebRequestListeners(tabId);
        //when all webRequest listeners are attached we can update tab to go to URL
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url:url});
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (
                lastOnCompletedTimestamp != null 
                && new (Date().getTime() - lastOnCompletedTimestamp < 3000)
            ) {
                //if more that 3 sencods past from last onCompleted event - detach events
                detachWebRequestListeners(tabId);
                            clearInterval(interval);

            }
        }, 200);
    }

    //creating empty tab without URL
    chrome.tabs.create(
        {active: false},
        function(tab) {
            onTabCreated(tab);
        }
    );

}

var urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://yandex.ru', 'http://.yahoo.com'];
for(var i in urls) {
    //this will start all urls in parallel, but I need to wait for execution of one url and only after this go to next one
    processURL(urls[i]);
}
```

**UPD:** I've found very nice `Deferred js` object (see http://cho45.stfuawsc.com/jsdeferred/#behavior ) It allows to loop through urls using `loop` or `next`, but we have to make some modifications, see Deferred tuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start processing each tab, only after you are done processing the previous one. This can be achieved by initiating the processing of a tab at the end of the previous tab's interval callback:

Change your code like this:

```
var urls = [...];
var processURL = function (idx) {
    if (idx >= urls.length) { return; }
    var url = urls[idx];
    ...
    var onTabCreated = function(tab) {
        ...
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            ...
            clearInterval(interval);
            processURL(idx + 1);
    ...
};
processURL(0);
```

---

<sub>BTW, `tabId = tab.tabId` **[should be](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab)** `tabId = tab.id`.</sub>

Comment: thank you for your comment. I understand your solution. I've also found another one using `Deferred js` object, see http://cho45.stfuawsc.com/jsdeferred/doc/Deferred.html